# Superfluous headers and footers when using longtable in revtex4

Tags: tables, longtable, revtex

There are two long tables in my LaTeX file: the first one should be supplied with headers and footers while the second one does not need such auxiliary lines.

How to solve that the headers and footers of the first long table should not be placed at the beginnings and the ends of the pages corresponding the second long table? The content of my LaTeX file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,preprint,aps, unsortedaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}
\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}

\begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{-3.0cm}
\setlength\LTright{-2.0cm}

\scriptsize

\begin{longtable}{ l r @{--} p{1.3cm} >{\centering}p{2.6cm}
  *{4}{p{1.25cm}} p{2.1cm}}
  %% headers and footers

  \caption{Table} \\
  \hline\hline
  \endfirsthead

  \mc{9}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \emph{Continued from previous page}} \\
  \hline
  aaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
  \hline
  \endhead

  \hline
  \mc{9}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
  \endfoot

  \hline\hline
  \endlastfoot

  %% body of table

  aaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
  aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
  aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii
\end{longtable}

\newpage

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: First Table]
[image: Second table]

Comment: just not write them if you not needed :-) column  heads and foots are not obligatory.

Comment: No, I do need them in the case of the first table, but for some reasons, these lines are shown for the second table, as well. I have attached the pictures of the tables.

Comment: you misunderstand my comment ... (i) `longtable` is used when the tale is longer than one page. in such cases it automatically break at beginning of the row, which otherwise would spill out of text area (ii) for shorter tables are intended environments as `tabular`, `tabular*` etc (iii) from your *mwe* is not clear are you have two really long tables which you use on a wrong way, or two short independent tables. (iv) if you not like to have at second part of `longtable` a column headers, than not use `\endfirsthead`,`\endhead` etc. and insert just one `\caption` on beginning of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can define empty heads and foots for the second table like

```
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\endfirsthead
\endhead
\endfoot
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
\end{longtable}
```

With the following complete code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,preprint,aps, unsortedaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs}
\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn}

\begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{-3.0cm}
\setlength\LTright{-2.0cm}

\scriptsize

\begin{longtable}{ l r @{--} p{1.3cm} >{\centering}p{2.6cm} *{4}{p{1.25cm}} p{2.1cm}}
  %% headers and footers
  \caption{Table} \\
  \hline\hline
\endfirsthead
  \mc{9}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \emph{Continued from previous page}} \\
  \hline
  aaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
  \hline
\endhead
  \hline
  \mc{9}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
  \hline\hline
\endlastfoot
  %% body of table
  aaa & \mc{2}{c}{bbb--ccc} & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
  aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii \\
  aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii
\end{longtable}

\newpage

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\endfirsthead
\endhead
\endfoot
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

you get the two tables:

[image: table 1]

and

[image: table 2]